# How to Join a Date column with a time Column in criteria?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I'm having some serious trouble with this one, the database from where I work isn't the best modeled, and so it has 4 columns in a table with a period information: column 1: start DATE, column 2: start HOUR, column 3:end DATE and column 4:end HOUR. I was tasked to create a criteria query in which one of the filters is de start or end "date" but in reality it's not only the date, it has to count the hour of the 2nd column.
Question is, is there a way to "merge" the date of one and de hour of another column ? something around this:

```
Expression endDateJoin = criteriaBuilder.concat(root.get("termino"),root.get("horarioFim"));

statusAuthorization.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(endDateJoin, new Date()));
```

I don't have a solid code to show you guys, this problem is slowing me down

Thanks for any help !

Comment: This is going to be database specific. We need to know the database and the actual column types to be able to provide actual advice.

Comment: Sure ! Here we use an Oracle 10g database and all four columns are DATE type, thanks !

Comment: The problem here is that while you can extract the individual fields from a date with something like TO_CHAR(date, ‘HH24′) in order to use this in a WHERE clause you are going to have to execute this against every single row in your table.  You may need to instead build a function based index that will allow indexed lookups https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes. You still pay a performance cost but you pay it at indexing time instead of query time.